# Altium Black Squares From Footprint Ultra librarian

Tags: altium

I have made a PCB on alitum designer and have generated gerber and NC drill files and Zipped it up and put into the osh park website that allows you to view what you are submitting.

[image: Osh Park Viewer]

However as you can see I have this black squares on my board which should be surface mount jst connectors of which I got the footprint from ultra librarian. (Example https://app.ultralibrarian.com/details/2676f7bd-d30e-11e9-b85e-0ad2c9526b44/JST/S3B-PH-SM4-TB-LF--SN-?uid=624fab468b7bbd88&exports=AltiumDesigner)

But when I am looking at my PCB on altium I see nothing wrong.
[image: PCB Connector view Altium]

Will this effect my board when it is manufactured?

If anyone has any advice or know why it is doing this please let me know.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Altium, I generated Gerber files and opened a CAM document with those Gerber files. For basic PCBS you will only need 8 layers. The black squares came from one of the mechanical layers from the downloaded component.

[image]

Comment: it's generally a good idea to specify the board outline as a mechanical layer. This explicitly tells the manufacturer, regardless of what where you think the board edge is, this is exactly where it is. They can 'guess' based off your design but they can also get it wrong.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I put the board outline on Mechanical Layer 1. I guess you could also use the keep-out layer as your board outline

Comment: Don't use the keep-out layer as the board outline. Leave the keep-out for what its intended, to control placement of tracks, pads, components etc. Mechanical layer with a note to the fab to indicate that GMx is your outline = winning

Answer (score 2):

If the pink layer is solder mask, then it's doing exactly what you told it to do.

Solder mask is a **negative** layer. You put features in the solder mask layer in your design is where you want solder mask removed, not where you want the solder mask to cover.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your answer. Can you explain again.

Comment: @Newbie. See the pink area on your design? That's telling the manufacturer (OSH) "take the solder mask away from this area". And then their drawings show the solder mask taken away from that area. So they are doing exactly what your design tells them to do.

Comment: so how would you recommend to change the settings of the component to allow if to show up correctly like the rest of the components?

Comment: What do you mean? If the vendor recommends removing solder mask under their connector, then everything is fine and you shouldn't change anything.

Comment: What do the gerbers look like when you view them in Altium?